# Circuitikz: completing scheme containing op amps

Tags: circuitikz

I request anyone to give latex code for this diagram.

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
(0,0) node[op amp] (op1) {}
(op1.-) to[short,*-*] ++(-0.8,0)
to [R,l=$R_1$,*-*] (-3.8,0.5) node(ex){}
to [short,*-o] ++ (-0.5,0) coordinate(ex1)
(op1.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.0) coordinate (leftC)
(op1.+) to ++(0,-1) node[cground]{}
(op1.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,1) coordinate (leftR)
to[R,l=$R_2$] (leftR -| op1.out)
to[short,-*] (op1.out);
\draw %----------------------------------------------Change
(op1.out)++(3.5,-0.5)node[op amp] (op2){}
(op1.out) to[R,l=$R$,o-*] (op2.-)
(op2.-) to [short,-*] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC2)
to [C,l=$C$] (leftC2 -| op2.out)
to [short,-*] (op2.out)
to [short,-o] ++ (0.5,0) coordinate(end2)
(op2.+) to ++(0,-1) node[cground]{};
\draw %----------------------------------------------Change
(end2)++(3.5,-0.5)node[op amp] (op3){}
(end2) to[R,l=$R$,o-*] (op3.-)
(op3.-) to [short,-*] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC3)
to [C,l=$C$] (leftC3 -| op3.out)
to [short,-*] (op3.out)
to [short,-o] ++ (0.5,0) coordinate(end3)
(op3.+) to ++(0,-1) node[cground]{};
\draw %----------------------------------------------Change
(end3)++(3.5,-0.5)node[op amp] (op4){}
(end3) to[R,l=$R$,o-*] (op4.-)
(op4.-) to [short,-*] ++(0,1.5) coordinate (leftC4)
to [C,l=$C$] (leftC4 -| op4.out)
to [short,-*] (op4.out)
to [short,-o] ++ (0.5,0) coordinate(end4)
(op4.+) to ++(0,-1) node[cground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
```

I have written the above code. I was unable to draw 6 op amps in a single diagram, one op amp needs to be reversed.

[image]

Comment: You asked a "do-it-for-me" question earlier today which was relatively basic and someone helped, now you want this complicated diagram done for free whilst showing no effort, what have you attempted?

Comment: The purpose of this site is to build a library of knowledge which will help future users with the same problem. Please rephrase your request in a way which shows how far you got yourself and then break it down into specific problems which will be helpful for more people as it is unlikely that they will want to draw the exact same diagram as you.

Comment: Please also pay more attention to choosing suitable tags. Users fixed the tags on your previous question for you, yet you choose the same inappropriate tag for this question again.

Comment: dear sir plz do help me by going through my answer

Comment: I took a liberty and change title of your question. Now it should be more meaningful. If you not liked, please revert my editing.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

I draw above image in three steps:

- In the first step I redraw main chain of op amps where at their placement I used relative coordinates and defining nodes anchor at their negative inputs.
- In the second step was added output op amp, named op5, with its feedback loops. It is positioned below of `op3` op amp
  by use `node distance` option.
- The last was feedback op amp, named `op6`, and feedback loops to the first op amp (`op1`) in chain.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw
    (0,0)   node[op amp] (op1) {}
    (op1.+) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[cground]{}
    (op1.-) to [R,a=$R_1$,-o] ++ (-2,0) node[left] {$V_{\textrm{in}}$}
    (op1.-) to[short,*-]    ++ (0,1)  coordinate (leftR)
            to[R=$R_2$] (leftR -| op1.out)
            to[short,-o] (op1.out)
%---------------------------------------------- op2
            to[R=$R$,-*]    ++ (2,0)
            node[op amp, anchor=-] (op2){}
    (op2.+) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[cground]{}            
    (op2.-) -- ++(0,1) coordinate (leftC2)
            to [C=$C$]  (leftC2 -| op2.out)
            to [short,-*]   (op2.out)
            to [short,-*]   ++ (0.5,0) coordinate (end2)
            to [R=$R$,-*]   ++ (2,0)
%---------------------------------------------- op3
            node[op amp, anchor=-] (op3){}
    (op3.+) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[cground]{}
    (op3.-) -- ++(0,1) coordinate (leftC3)
            to [C=$C$]  (leftC3 -| op3.out)
            to [short,-*]   (op3.out)
            to [short,-*]   ++ (0.5,0) coordinate (end3)
            to [R=$R$,-*]   ++ (2,0)
%---------------------------------------------- op4
            node[op amp, anchor=-] (op4){}
    (op4.+) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[cground]{}
    (op4.-) -- ++(0,1) coordinate (leftC4)
            to [C=$C$]  (leftC4 -| op4.out)
            to [short,-*]   (op4.out)
            to [short,-*]   ++ (0.5,0) coordinate (end4)
            to [short,-o]   ++ (0.5,0) node[right] {$V_{1}$}
%---------------------------------------------- op5 + feedback loops
            node[op amp, below=4 of op3] (op5){}
    (op5.+) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[cground]{}
    (op2.out) |- (end2 |- op5.-)
            to [R=$R$,-*]   (op5.-)
    (op5.-) to[short,*-]    ++ (0,1)  coordinate (leftR5a)
            to[R=$1/A$] (leftR5a -| op5.out)
            to [short,-*]   (op5.out)
            to [short,-o]   ++ (0.5,0) node[right] {$V_{\textrm{out}}$}
    (leftR5a) to[short,*-]  ++ (0,1)  coordinate (leftR5b)
    (leftR5b) to [R=$1/C$,*-]   ++ (2,0) -| (op4.out)
    (leftR5b) to[short,*-]      ++ (0,1)  coordinate (leftR5c)
    (leftR5c) to [R=$1/B$]      ++ (2,0) -| (end3)
%---------------------------------------------- op6 + feedback loops
    (leftR) to[short,*-]    ++ (0,1)  coordinate (leftRa)
    (leftRa) to[R=$1/E$]    ++ (2,0) -| (end3)
    (leftRa) to[short,*-]   ++ (0,2)  coordinate (leftRb)
            to[R=$R$]       ++ (2,0)
            node[op amp, xscale=-1, anchor=out] (op6){}
    (op6.+) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[cground]{}
    (op6.-) to[short,-*] (op6.- -| end2)  coordinate (in6a)
            to[R=$1/D$]   ++ (0,-2) -- (end2)
    (in6a)  -- (op6.- -| end4)  
            to[R=$1/D$]   ++ (0,-2) -- (end4)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```